# What are some good user login/authentication libraries or protocols to use with Python on Google App Engine?

Tags: passwords, authentication, google, user-management, python

I've read elsewhere (http://forums.udacity.com/questions/6028436/bcrypt-not-suitable-for-pythongae) that bcrypt is not suitable for use on Google App Engine. What are some good ways to create a user signup/login system (with usernames/emails & passwords) without rolling your own when using Google App Engine for Python? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The PBKDF2 algorithm available from the [passlib](http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.pbkdf2_digest.html) library will do the trick.

It doesn't have some appealing properties of bcrypt such as being hard to speedup using GPUs but it is still a strong password hashing with a configurable iteration count.